# Epigraph before \chapter and \section

Tags: positioning, epigraphs

I have read the epigraph documentation, but sadly I do not understand how to put my quote before the \chapter and \section entry (same page).

Could someone give me a hint, please?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,
    bibliography=totoc,
    toc=listof,
    captions=tableheading,
    headings=small,
    listof=entryprefix
    ]
    {scrbook}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                     
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[language=autobib,
    backend=biber,
    citetracker=true,
    autolang=other,
    style=authoryear-comp
    ]{biblatex}


\usepackage{epigraph}
    \setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{1.0\baselineskip}
    %\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
    %\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.5\textwidth}
    \setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{.25\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}


\begin{document}
\part{PART}

\epigraph{Poor cultural foundations were a significant driver of the 2008–2009 financial crisis(in common with many past crises). Behaviors that do not meet banks’ desired values and conduct continue to be a problem.}{Group of Thirty (2015), p. 18}

\chapter{CHAPTER}
\section{SECTION}

Text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to increase the amount of space before the chapter heading.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  bibliography=totoc,
  toc=listof,
  captions=tableheading,
  headings=small,
  listof=entryprefix,
]{scrbook}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                     
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[
  language=autobib,
  backend=biber,
  citetracker=true,
  autolang=other,
  style=authoryear-comp,
]{biblatex}


\usepackage{epigraph}

%\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{1.0\baselineskip}
%\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
%\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.5\textwidth}
%\setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{.25\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}


\begin{document}
\part{PART}

\chapter{CHAPTER}

\epigraphhead[20]{%
  \epigraph{Poor cultural foundations were a significant 
    driver of the 2008–2009 financial crisis(in common
    with many past crises). Behaviors that do not meet
    banks’ desired values and conduct continue to be a
    problem.}{Group of Thirty (2015), p. 18}}

\section{SECTION}

Text.

\end{document}
```

The argument `[20]` is the distance of the bottom of the epigraph from the upper margin of the text block.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But now I have an issue that is already adressed in the manual. To gain more space between the the epigraph and the chapter, I use \dropchapter{15in} and \undodrop. Unfortunately the heading does not drop! Any suggestions?

Comment: @TRJW That's for the standard classes, you're using `scrbook`.

Comment: Any ideas how I could modify this!? :S