# epigraph plus standalone gives unexpected results

Tags: standalone, epigraphs

I want to write a long document therefore I will split it in several files and use the package `standalone` to import them. I also want to add epigraphs before the chapters names, thus I use the package `epigraph` and the command `\epigrahhead` as recommended in the documentation and in the following [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436425/epigraph-before-chapter-and-section).

But with this combination, the last epigraph printed is the one of the first chapter.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{chapter2.tex}
    \documentclass[a4paper]{book}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{epigraph}

    \begin{document}

        \chapter{Chapter title}
        \epigraphhead[20]{
            \epigraph{\itshape Computer programming is an art, because it applies 
                accumulated knowledge to the world, because it requires skill and ingenuity, 
                and especially because it produces objects of beauty.
            }{Donald Knuth, \textit{"Computer Programming as an Art". Communications of the ACM, Volume 17, Issue 12, dl.acm.org., December 1974}}
        }

        \section{section title}
        Text again.

        \chapter{Last chapter}
        \epigraphhead[20]{
            \epigraph{Last epigraph}{ Probably someone}
        }

        \section{Last section}
        Last text.

    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{CHAPTER}
    \epigraphhead[20]{%
        \epigraph{Poor cultural foundations were a significant 
            driver of the 2008–2009 financial crisis(in common
            with many past crises). Behaviors that do not meet
            banks’ desired values and conduct continue to be a
            problem.}{Group of Thirty (2015), p. 18}
    }

    \section{SECTION}
    Text.

    \input{./chapter2.tex}

\end{document}
```

So I wonder why there is this unexpected results ?

#### EDIT

Thanks to the answer given by egreg, it seems that commenting the first epigraph only implies a different behaviour:

```
    \chapter{CHAPTER}
    %\epigraphhead[20]{%
    %   \epigraph{Poor cultural foundations were a significant 
    %       driver of the 2008–2009 financial crisis(in common
    %       with many past crises). Behaviors that do not meet
    %       banks’ desired values and conduct continue to be a
    %       problem.}{Group of Thirty (2015), p. 18}
    %}

    \section{SECTION}
    Text.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that what's typeset when `standalone` is in force, like when you `\input{chapter2.tex}`, is done in a group.

With `epigraph`, the text of the epigraph is stored in the temporary control sequence `@epitemp and some juggling with the page style is done.

What happens with your very short final chapter is that the input file ends before the chapter page is shipped out, so the group is ended and the value of `\@epitemp` restored to what it was before `\input`. Hence you get the last epigraph before `\input`.

Add `\clearpage` at the end of the short chapter.

```
\begin{filecontents}{chapter2.tex}
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}
%\epigraphhead[20]{
%   \epigraph{\itshape Computer programming is an art, because it applies 
%              accumulated knowledge to the world, because it requires skill and ingenuity, 
%              and especially because it produces objects of beauty.
%   }{Donald Knuth, \textit{``Computer Programming as an Art''. 
%     Communications of the ACM, Volume 17, Issue 12, dl.acm.org., December 1974}}
%}

\section{section title}
Text again.

\clearpage

\chapter{Last chapter}
\epigraphhead[20]{
  \epigraph{Last epigraph}{Probably someone}
}

\section{Last section}
Last text.

\clearpage % <----- HERE

\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}

\chapter{CHAPTER}
\epigraphhead[20]{%
  \epigraph{Poor cultural foundations were a significant 
            driver of the 2008–2009 financial crisis(in common
            with many past crises). Behaviors that do not meet
            banks’ desired values and conduct continue to be a
            problem.}{Group of Thirty (2015), p. 18}
}

\section{SECTION}
Text.

\input{./chapter2.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying your solution and I commented the  whole `\epigraphead` block which made disappear the last epigraph. Isn't it the same kind of problem ?

Comment: @R.N If you remove the epigraph, what do you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself well, I remove only the first epigraph and that made disappear the last one. So I expect to have the second and third epigraph printed. I will edit my question to make the clearer the situation.

Comment: @R.N Same problem. Short chapter. LaTeX cannot realize that an epigraph is needed.

Comment: Ok but it is possible to solve this kind of situation also ?

Comment: @R.N I added a full example, with the first epigraph commented out.

Comment: Thank you. You convince me: it is easier to use `\clearpage` !