# epigraph and titlesec+titletoc create misbehaviour

Tags: titlesec, titletoc, epigraphs

I use titlesec and titletoc to create my own style of chapter that contains a minitoc after the chapter title. 
And I use epigraph when I want to have one before the chapter title.

I am currently writing a chapter that contains multiple sections, so the minitoc have to continue on the next page. This leads to a wrong printing of the epigraph plus the lasts sections are not printed in the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        


\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \newlength{\HeightBeforeChap}
    \setlength{\HeightBeforeChap}{0pt}

    % redefine chapter style
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\filright}{}{0pt} 
        {\vspace*{\HeightBeforeChap} \\! \Huge \bfseries\raggedleft}
        [\vspace*{4pc}%
            \startcontents
            {\raggedright\bfseries \large Mini ToC \endgraf}
            \titlerule
            \vspace{6pt}
            \printcontents{p}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
            \vspace{6pt}
            \titlerule
        ]

\usepackage{epigraph}
        \renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}
        \setlength\epigraphwidth{.55\textwidth}
        \makeatletter
            \@ifundefined{HeightBeforeChap}
            {% \HeightBeforeChap not defined
                }
            {% \HeightBeforeChap defined
                \renewcommand{\dropchapter}[1]{\setlength{\HeightBeforeChap}{#1} }
            }%
        \makeatother


\begin{document}

    \dropchapter{11pt}
    \chapter{title 1}

    \epigraphhead[40]{
            \epigraph{\itshape Computer programming is an art, because it applies 
                accumulated knowledge to the world, because it requires skill and ingenuity, 
                and especially because it produces objects of beauty.
            }{Donald Knuth, \textit{"Computer Programming as an Art". Communications of the ACM, Volume 17, Issue 12, dl.acm.org., December 1974}}
        }
    \dropchapter{0cm}

    \section{section 1}
    \subsection{title}
    \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 2}
    \section{section 3}
    \section{section 4}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 5}
    \section{section 6}
    \section{section 7}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 8}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 9}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 10}
    \section{section 11}
    \section{section 12}
    \section{section 13}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 14}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 15}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 16}
    \section{section 17}
    \section{section 18}
    \section{section 19}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 20}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section 21}
        \subsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    \section{section}

    \chapter{title 2}
    \section{title}

\end{document}
```

Here is the results that I get:[image][image]

Thanks to the answer of [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470056/epigraph-plus-standalone-gives-unexpected-results), I think that is related to termination of the page needed to print the epigraph, but I no idea about how to solve it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since their is not a single comments even after the bounty I put, I come up with an ugly solution, waiting for better solutions from SE.

The ugly one:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \newlength{\HeightBeforeChap}
    \setlength{\HeightBeforeChap}{0pt}
    \newcommand{\BeforeChapCmd}{}
    \newcommand{\BeforeChap}[1]{\gdef\BeforeChapCmd{#1}}

    % redefine chapter style
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\filright}{}{0pt} 
        {\BeforeChapCmd\leavevmode\vspace*{\HeightBeforeChap}\BeforeChap{}\\ \Huge \bfseries\raggedleft}
        [\vspace*{4pc}%
            \startcontents
            {\raggedright\bfseries \large Mini ToC \endgraf}
            \titlerule
            \vspace{6pt}
            \printcontents{p}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
            \vspace{6pt}
            \titlerule
            \leavevmode
        ]

\usepackage{epigraph}
    \renewcommand{\epigraphhead}[2][]{\BeforeChap{#2}   

\begin{document}

%   \dropchapter{11pt}
    \epigraphhead[40]{
                 \epigraph{\itshape Computer programming is an art, because it applies 
                     accumulated knowledge to the world, because it requires skill and ingenuity, 
                     and especially because it produces objects of beauty.
                 }{Donald Knuth, \textit{"Computer Programming as an Art". Communications of the ACM, Volume 17, Issue 12, dl.acm.org., December 1974}}
             }
    \chapter{title 1}
%    \dropchapter{0cm}

     \section{section 1}
     \subsection{title}
     \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 2}
     \section{section 3}
     \section{section 4}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 5}
     \section{section 6}
     \section{section 7}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 8}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 9}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 10}
     \section{section 11}
     \section{section 12}
     \section{section 13}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
         blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla.
     \section{section 14}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 15}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 16}
     \section{section 17}
     \section{section 18}
     \section{section 19}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 20}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section 21}
         \subsection{title}
         \subsubsection{title}
     \section{section}

     \chapter{title 2}
     \section{title}

\end{document}
```